# Variable in template is undefined

Tags: php

I'm trying to load a template in `print_table()` function. If I uncomment the include_once code above, it will work. Why? the `get_template function` does exactly the same. As it is now it says $people is undefined.

```
function get_template( $template_name ) {
include_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $template_name;
}

function print_table( $people ) {
// include_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'html/table.php';
get_template( 'html/table.php' );
}
```

in html/table.php

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Date</th>
</tr>
<?php dd($people); ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I think $people variable is invisble in get_template function scope. Try to pass this parameter to get_template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of variable scope. `$people` is not defined in your function `get_template()` (as well said in other answers).

To be **reusable**, you also could pass an associative array that contains all variables and use [`extract()`](https://php.net/extract) to use them as variable in your template:

```
function get_template($template_name, $data) {
    extract($data);
    include_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $template_name;
}

function print_table($people) {
    get_template('html/table.php', ['people'=>$people]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The included file is evaluated in the scope of the function including it. `print_table` has a variable `$people` in scope. `get_template` does not, since you're not passing the variable to `get_template`; it only has a `$template_name` variable in scope.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959577/476.

Answer (score 1):

`$people` is an argument of function `print_table()`, that's why it is available in the file included by `print_table()`.

But it is not available in the file included by the `get_template()` function because in the context of the `get_template()` function there is no variable named `$people` defined.

Read about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).